# VBComponent refer to sheet by tab name

Tags: vba, excel

```
Set VBProj = ActiveWorkbook.VBProject
        Set VBComp = VBProj.VBComponents("Sheet10")
```

I have the code above. Currently Sheet10 is named as SummaryTab in the excel tab. I want to refer to the VBComponent using the name in the excel tab. Meaning that I want to use something like

```
Set VBComp = VBProj.VBComponents("SummaryTab")
```

However, the above code is giving me errors. how can I fix this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use

```
Set VBComp = VBProj.VBComponents(Worksheets("SummaryTab").CodeName)
```

Comment: @ShaiRado - LOL - but I'm on **holidays** - I don't have as much spare time when I'm on holidays!

Comment: `Set VBComp = VBProj.VBComponents(Activesheet.CodeName)` works too.